# How can I give a graph nodes fixed position in graphviz and how can i make the edges not overlapped?

Tags: graphviz

I have seen some similar questions here, but the answers dont solve my problem.

I want to draw a graph. I write some code like this:

```
digraph {
  {rank = same a b c d e f }
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
  a -> f
  b -> d -> f
  b -> f
}
```

but the result is that some of the edges overlapped each other.

So my question is how can I fix the edge to make it not overlap 
and I also wanna know how can I give the node a fixed position? There is no problem this graph. But some times when I wanna a graph with a sequence of

```
a b c d e f
```

but when i create some edges and the sequence will change like:

```
a->e b c d f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the attribute `pos` of a node or edge to specify coordinates. To see where `dot` places your nodes and edges you can simply run `dot myinputfile.dot` without any output parameter. This will produce the dot file with added coordinates (among other additions).
Based on this you can force `dot` to place some or all nodes at certain coordinates.

Comment: Wow. I was about to post a very similar question after struggling with this issue for hours, and I came across this gem of an answer (with no upvotes? come on now...). You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.